# Crystal Report: Remove empty extra line detail section in excel

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to export report in excel but detail section give extra line per record. i want report with only single line for single record[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp3CU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the bottom of your section is touching the bottom of every field in the section. If any fields are slightly taller/shorter or there is a gap between the field and the section boundary this normally happens.

If you believe that not be the case, possibly share a screenshot of the report in design mode and it may help.

Comment: Thanks.All feild have same height but some field have extra data. so this field are set to"can grow". so extra line for extra growing rows.

Comment: This Happening only in excel.